# vSphere iSCSi not support VM Cluster?

Tags: datastore, iscsi, vsphere

I'm building a virtual machine cluster using vSphere 5.1.

I'm finding solution for data storage.

I want iSCSi but when I see information on vsphere documentation I see with iSCSi vSphere don't supports "VM Cluster" but supports HA and DRS. I known HA only enable when create a "Cluster (Host cluster)".

[image]

I don't know exactly "VM Cluster" is what.

Please help me explain different of "VM Cluster" and "Host Cluster".

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

a "VM Cluster" would be a cluster of two virtual machines running Windows MSCS for example. This "VM Cluster" would run on the ESXi hypervizor hosts, or a "Host Cluster".
A "Host Cluster" is a cluster of 2 or more physical machines running ESXi.

The table you found tells you you can't do any form of VM clustering when using Native iSCSI (the ESXi iSCSI initiator) on the ESXi hosts.

You can however do Host clustering using native iSCSI. No problem. Just don't do VM clustering when you use Native iSCSI.

Check http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1037959 for more info

Answer (score 0):

When you create the iSCSI target, you must check the "Allow multiple concurrent iSCSI connections (Clustering)" option